# How to shift elements forward and backwards in a array list in java

Tags: java, list

I'm needing some help in rotating a array.  It would shift the element in the list either forward and backwards while pushing anything with it.If I'm starting with [a, b, c, d] then,
I'm expecting [b, c, d, a] for rotating forward and
[d, a, b, c] for rotating backwards
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:  I would prefer a built-in function. Thanks!

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve the problem yourself. We'd be glad to help you after that.

Comment: I've tried but no idea how to do it.